# Need form in located in a SharePoint 2010 InfoPath web part to retain data submitted at the same time

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have created a form for use during a meeting. Multiple people need to click approve at the same time. The issue is if they all are in the form at the same time, it is only going to keep the last approval and resets the fields the others have approved... as there approval was not there when the form was opened. I guess I should have seen this coming.  Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Use two lists with a parent/child relationship.

You need a master list with a unique ID and a detail list where the Master ID is assigned to the new list items to define the relationship. In the Master List you can customize the display form to contain a list view of the related items in the Detail list and a link to add new items to that detail list. A little bit of JavaScript will ensure that a new item in the Detail list gets the Master item's ID assigned automatically.

Clear as mud? The SharePoint Hillbilly has a video tutorial for [2007](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2009/12/08/creating-a-sharepoint-list-parentchild-relationship-ndash-video-remix.aspx) and [2010](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2010/12/16/creating-a-sharepoint-parentchild-list-relationshipndash-sharepoint-2010-edition.aspx).

If you go through the material (the 2007 stuff is good to understand the approach), you'll find that there are two techniques, one using SharePoint Designer, the other one without SPD.

Back to your meeting: Before the meeting, create an item in the Master list. Everybody can see the item on their screen and click to create a related item in the Detail list. They can all save their related item at the same time, since these are individual list items in the Detail list. Refresh the display view of the Master list item to see everybody's replies.